# Display complete command line (including arguments) for Windows process

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, process

I want to display a process's command line (including any arguments) from the command line itself. In other words, I want to show the "Command Line" column in the Task Manager but from a command line. Is this possible?

For example, the output might look something like

```
C:\java\bin\java.exe -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://localproxy -Dport=8331
```

Comment: [How do I find out command line arguments of a running program?](https://superuser.com/q/415360/241386)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Microsoft's official [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). It can do exactly this and has many many more useful features.

Comment: One very useful note, after starting Process Explorer for the first time, right-click the table header ("Process" | "CPU" | "Private Bytes" | etc.) and add the "Command Line" column for the info you want to see. Very, very helpful tool, allows you to see what scripts IT is running on your machine...

Answer (score 27):

Wmic.exe will show you what you are looking for:

```
wmic path win32_process get name,commandline > commandline.txt
```

Java looks like:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\jqs.exe" -service -config "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\deploy\jqs\jqs.conf"
```

For all available attributes, try:

```
wmic path win32_process get /format:list
```

Comment: I am getting error "Invalid GET expression" for the comma put between name and commandline. Rest all is working like charm.

Comment: I'm guessing you're running this within a batch file?  try escaping the comma like so:  "wmic path win32_process get name^, commandline"

Comment: I was running it from powershell, will try this and update.

Comment: Ok - If you issue the 'all available attributes command' noted above, in powershell, you get expected results.  On reading further,  in power shell, the comma does indeed need to be escaped.  However, you use the forward quote: ` to do so:  wmic path win32_process get name`, commandline

Comment: If you're running the first command, remove the space after the comma so that it looks like this:
`wmic path win32_process get name,commandline > commandline.txt`

That will remove the "Invalid GET expression" error

Comment: +1 thank you! Process Explorer fails if the command line is too long, but this command works just fine!

Comment: You can also pipe the output of `wmic` to `findstr java` for example

Comment: wmic.exe is no longer provided in windows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic

Comment: Note: This was answered 12 years ago. you can continue to use the powershell solutions listed above. They all utilize get-ciminstance for the relevant classname: Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_process | where processid -match 26692 | select name,commandline